# How to show main report with empty linked subreports in Crystal Reports?

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Reports report which contains a main report and three subreports. The data tables used in subreports are linked with main report's data table. In subreports also I've given linking.

Now when I have data in subreports, all comes out fine. But if there is no data in subreports, the main report is also shown as blank.

How to make the main report show results despite (some) sub reports being empty?

Answer (score 0):

Subreports only run *after* the main report has retrieved it's data.  So unless you have set up some fairly complex suppression conditions using shared variables, there is no way that a linked subreport can 'blank' the main report.  You can confirm this by running the same report criteria with all of the subreports deleted.  You will likely still have the same blank main report. The cause is more likely to be an inner join in the main report.

And there is one final possibility that I hope no one finds insulting.  Depending on how the subreports are arranged, it could be possible that adding the subreports causes the first page to be blank while the report starts on the second page. This is caused by the 'keep together' properties of sections and groups.  I have had clients call me to troubleshoot blank reports when the data was on page 2.